# openpyxl delete rows and update the excel file

Tags: openpyxl

I just simply want to delete some rows from the excel sheet and update the file, But seems like there is no way to update the file. If so please tell

Secondly if i try to delete the rows/columns and and try to iterate over the rows again then again those rows or columns being showing in the data.

```
for row in (0, 1, 2, 3):
    wb.delete_rows(row)

for c in (0, 1, 3):
    wb.delete_cols(c)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is there any method .save(). like wb.save()?

Comment: if yes, then try to save wb object after each update

Comment: Yes there is a method save, but it doesn't let you update the current state of the file or to write somewhere else

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the pandas library for this.

You will have other features as well like merging cells, groupings. This would help you more with extensive features with your data set.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("excelfile.xls")

pd.drop(['col1', 'col2'])
```

for more detail please visit below link
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html